# How to Initialize Parse in a service and update ParseObject

Tags: android, android-service, parse-platform

My application should update some data in Parse.com server. The service starts automatically when the phone booted (with a broadcast receiver - BOOT_COMPLETED) and should access the data in the server and update few fields.

The problem - Parse cannot be initialized in a service, it can be done only in an onCreate method.
In my application I have no Activty, only a broadcast receiver which starts the service.

My question is how can I update ParseObject within my service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create objects, create a class having all the methods implemented, and after that when the service starts, here provide authentication id and client key, now create ParseObject and use to update your data.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? and where should I call Parse.initialize() method? @naveed

Comment: because we need app id and client key to communicate with the server, I also implemented my project on Parse, therefore I knew the problem

Answer (score 0):

onCreate in your Application class is the best place, IMO. It's a database, right? We want our databases to be like a singleton, yeah? extend Application =]

and like naveed said, making a nice Parse utility class is a good idea

Also encrypt your keys...

```
try {
        Parse.initialize( this, Utils.deString( assetManager.open( "parse_id" ) ), 
                         Utils.deString( assetManager.open( "parse_secret" ) ) );
    } catch(IOException e) {Log.e( TAG, "error handling Parse keys " + e.toString( ) );}
```

Comment: But I have no class with onCreate method in this process. so where should I initialize the Parse? and how can I make it a singleton? @anthropic

Comment: ah... you do not want to make it a singleton--they are an anti-pattern IMHO--you want to make it *like* a singleton; that means writing a class that extends Application. onCreate in there.